# Background transperancy in imagerotate()

Tags: php, gd

Since last 2 days, I was trying to add transperancy to the background after rotating an image using imagerotate() PHP-GD function.

But, to my great disappointment, it's not working at all.

It's just giving out a black background behind it.

Here's my code -

```
$patchImageS    =   'image.png'; // the image to be patched over the final bg
$patchImage =   imagecreatefrompng($patchImageS); // resource of image to be patched
$patchImage     =   imagerotate($patchImage, 23, 0, 0);
imagepng($patchImage,'tt.png');
```

I tried to change the parameters being passed in function to

imagerotate($patchImage, 23, 5, 0);

imagerotate($patchImage, 23, 0, 5);

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you haven't acceptet ansers on all you old questions - if you find an answer, you should do so, otherwise people might not want to help you anymore...

Comment: @oezi sorry ... but i am new to stackoverflow and didn't know that there was any feature like that ... thanks :-) for pointing out ... btw, just accepted answers for my questions till now :-)

Comment: i updated my answer so you can see an example of imagesavealpha there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a number of 99% finished answers, here's the solution I've found:

```
// Create, or create from image, a PNG canvas
$png = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// Preserve transparency
imagesavealpha($png , true);
$pngTransparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($png , 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($png , 0, 0, $pngTransparency);

// Rotate the canvas including the required transparent "color"
$png = imagerotate($png, $rotationAmount, $pngTransparency);

// Set your appropriate header
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Render canvas to the browser
imagepng($png);

// Clean up
imagedestroy($png);
```

The key here is to include your imagecolorallocatealpha() in your imagerotate() call...

Comment: This might not work. You have to put "imagesavealpha($png , true);" after "$png = imagerotate($png, $rotationAmount, $pngTransparency);"

Comment: Um, what!? The whole point of issuing the command to save the Alpha channels is to keep that data before filling the canvas... Unless you have an example of my method NOT working; this is the method used across many different sites including the documentation for the libraries...

Comment: I see what you're saying, but my example still holds true. You are actually delegating memory for the fact that you want Alpha data to exist before filling that reserved space with Alpha data. It's the issue of needing a container before the data is stored there.

Comment: This code did not work for me, for sampling I used image at below link
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/92/ACDC_Back_in_Black.png

Comment: Ghanshyam, the code above won't help you when your image already has black in the background... You have to have a transparent PNG to work with from the beginning.

Comment: `imagesavealpha($png , true);` is optional in your code

Answer (score 4):

look for imagesavealpha() in the php-documentation - i think this is what you are looking for.

EDIT: here's an example:

```
$png = imagecreatefrompng('./alphachannel_example.png');

// Do required operations
$png = imagerotate($png, 23, 0, 0);

// Turn off alpha blending and set alpha flag
imagealphablending($png, false);
imagesavealpha($png, true);

// Output image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($png);
imagedestroy($png);
```

Comment: okay .Thanks for it ... i ll try it out.But will it work irrespective of the image extension ? Or we can always convert images to PNG .

Comment: i tried that ... but it still gives a white background and not a transperant one ...

Comment: This is marked as accepted answer but the original poster says it did not solve his problem. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This does not work for me!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having problems with `imagecopyresampled` or `imagerotate` with black bars on background, I have found a code example here:

https://qna.habr.com/q/646622#answer_1417035

```
        // get image sizes (X,Y)
        $wx = imagesx($imageW);
        $wy = imagesy($imageW);

        // create a new image from the sizes on transparent canvas
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($wx, $wy);

        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        $rotate = imagerotate($imageW, 280, $transparent);
        imagealphablending($rotate, true);
        imagesavealpha($rotate, true);

        // get the newest image X and Y
        $ix = imagesx($rotate);
        $iy = imagesy($rotate);

        //copy the image to the canvas
        imagecopyresampled($destImg, $rotate, 940, 2050, 0, 0, $ix, $iy, $ix, $iy);
```