# Not getting transparent background while rotating an image

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-rotation

I want to rotate an image with transparent background fill to uncovered zone.

I refereed [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) official documentation with syntax

```
// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
```

but did not get success.

After rotation I am getting image with black color fill to uncovered zone. like below

[image]

Original image is [here](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMu4_9JexvGYadBx1oIhfqgkP6GE1r96T9dS4iiYTd_IrpgcElnw)

I also have tried below command

```
$> convert -rotate 5 image.png image_rotated.png
```

Reference is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082472/php-imagerotate-ruins-alpha-on-png)

Above command I have used on png and jpg image, but I didn't get fruits..

Now I don't know where the things are going wrong ?? is there any problems with versions of library I am using ??

My php version is `PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this be the answer you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10148965/2221671

Comment: I tried that too, but it is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following command worked for me on `Debian wheezy 7.5` with `mageMagick 6.7.7-10`.

```
convert -background "rgba(0,0,0,0)" -rotate 5 images.jpg new.png
```

Specify `-background "rgba(0,0,0,0)"` it will set transparent background fill for output image. Also make sure to save output image in `.png` format (which supports transparency)

Hope It will help. :)

Note: By default `-rotate` option uses **Black** color to fill background.

**EDIT:**

Make sure `imagemagick` package is installed properly.

check version details:

```
$convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-08 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

If you are not getting similar output try checking for installation of package.

```
$sudo dpkg --get-selection | grep imagemagick
```

You might want to install that if its status is `deinstalled` in output of above command.

```
$sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: WOw, M happy for you, atleast I made your day, have a nice day ahead and gud luck :D

Answer (score 0):

since you are using php, I assume you will accept css code as answer? add these css to your image and it'll tilt

```
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
/* Opera */
-o-transform:rotate(45deg);
/* IE9 */
-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
```

edit:
so not css huh, try this instead

```
$source = imagerotate($source,$degree,0XFFFFFF00,0); //<-- FFFFFF00 = RRGGBBAA
//you might not need to disable blending, try if it's not working
//imagealphablending($source, false);
imagesavealpha($source, true);
//then user $source however you want
```

Comment: Thanks for taking interest in my problem, but I need to rotate an image and then overlay it on another big image at some angle. same way hundreds of images are there, and from those images one video file will be created that will be displayed on web.

I don't require to show any image on browser.