# How to rotate series of images with transparent backgrounds in PHP without imagerotate adding black?

Tags: php, png, transparency, gd, php-7.4

I have a lot of images, exported from blender, that I want to rotate. They all come with a transparent background. An example, 0009.png:
[image]
This image is 70w x 70h.

I'm trying to rotate this image using imagerotate. This does properly rotate the image, but the function evidently needs to allocate a larger canvas to make sure all the pixels of the original rectangular shape still exist in the newly rotated image. **The problem is that this function appears to put black in the added space.** I'm able to preserve the transparency of my original image, but the extra canvas space gets a black color no matter what I try. I'm running this script using PHP 7.4.3:

```php
$filename = './blender-output/0009.png';
echo "opening $filename\n";

$img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
if (!$img) {
    throw new Exception("failed to open $filename");
}

// not sure what this does
if (!imagealphablending($img, false)) {
    throw new Exception('failed to turn off alpha blending');
}

if (!imagesavealpha($img, true)) {
    throw new Exception('failed to turn on image save alpha');
}

$transparent_color = imagecolortransparent($img, null);
if ($transparent_color < 0) {
    throw new Exception('no trans color');
}

$angle_degs = 53.33;
echo "rotating $angle_degs\n";


// let us rotate the image using the transparent color above
// we cannot allocate a color for the new image because it does
// not exist yet
$imgrot = imagerotate(
    $img,
    $angle_degs,
    $transparent_color, // background color...needs to be transparent
);
if (!$imgrot) {
    throw new Exception('rotation failed');
}


// not sure what this does, other posts suggested it
if (!imagealphablending($imgrot, false)) {
    throw new Exception('failed to turn off alpha blending for imgrot');
}
if (!imagesavealpha($imgrot, true)) {
    throw new Exception('save alpha failed for imagerot');
}


// this sort of works, but really just makes a mess, and only catches top left corner
//$transparent_black = imagecolorallocatealpha($imgrot , 0, 0, 0, 127);
//imagefill($imgrot , 0, 0, $transparent_black);

// this doesn't work, black regions from imagerotate totally unaffected
// set black transparent, too
//$black = imagecolorallocate($imgrot, 0, 0, 0);
// this also doesn't work, leaves the triangular black regions from imagerotate
$black = imagecolorallocatealpha($imgrot, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$transparent_black = imagecolortransparent($imgrot, $black);



if (!imagepng($imgrot, './rotated.png', 0)) {
    throw new Exception('unable to write  rot for ' . $filename);
}
```

As you can see in this output file, the image is larger 99w x 99h, and the added areas are black:
[image]

I searched here on SO for answers and there are many people struggling with this function. The documentation is not very clear at all and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602263/black-background-when-rotating-image-with-php) does not work for me.

Can anyone tell me how I can rotate this image such that the new image maintains the original transparent background, but also keeps any new/expanded canvas transparent, as well? I also tried [imagefill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693585/background-transperancy-in-imagerotate) but that didn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

Although imagerotate returns a new image, you can apparently allocate a transparent alpha color on the image you want to rotate and then use this color when you call that function. This function properly rotates my images and applies a new, transparent color to the additional pixels that get added.

```php
$filename = './blender-output/0009.png';
echo "opening $filename\n";

$img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
if (!$img) {
        throw new Exception("failed to open $filename");
}

$angle_degs = 53.33;
echo "rotating $angle_degs\n";

// for some reason, we have to allocate a new transparent color from the old image? 
$transparent_black = imagecolorallocatealpha(
        $img,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        127
);

// let us rotate the image using the transparent_black above
// interestingly, allocating a color from the image being rotated
// works for the new image? a bit counterintuitive
$imgrot = imagerotate(
        $img,
        $angle_degs,
        $transparent_black
);
if (!$imgrot) {
        throw new Exception('rotation failed');
}


if (!imagepng($imgrot, './rotated.png', 0)) {
        throw new Exception('unable to write  rot for ' . $filename);
}
```